# Is there something like mysql_num_rows in Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing a simple program in Java, to connect to MySQL. I try to write a simple query to only check if username and password (typed by me when I run the program) are in my database.

Since I have not so much experience with JDBC, I'd like to know if Java has a method like PHP's [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), to check if a specific piece of information is in my database.

Comment: if there isn't, then you can just `select count(*) ...` and retrieve that row of data and see what the field's count is.

Comment: how about select count(*) from ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple SELECT statement:

```
String username = "..."; //the username, it could be a method parameter
String password = "..."; //the password, it could be a method parameter
Connection con = .... //retrieve the connection the way you're doing it now
//replace ... for the data you want/need from user
String sql = "SELECT ... FROM user WHERE name = ? and password = ?";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, username);
pstmt.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    //read the data from ResultSet
}
rs.close();
pstmt.close();
con.close();
```

Comment: I try what you suggested me and it's ok.. before I used not an instance of PreparedStatement but of Statement. The "problem" is that i need to do some practice with this method and how I have to write query... but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `JDBC`, just send a `SELECT` statement to the DB with the correct SQL query.
Then you'll get a `ResultSet` back. Then check if it has any rows or what rows it has.
Based on that you determine if the user record exists or not.

[ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)